# Git branching: easily merging a third branch into two conflicting branches

Tags: git

I have the following situation in git: One "stable" branch and one "unstable" branch. The unstable branch contains bugs which I try to find by running both the stable and unstable branches on the same input and comparing their output logs.

Now, my logging framework is not good enough for this debug. So I want to improve my logging class. I create a new branch, "log_improve" from "stable". After I'll finish working on it, I'll merge it back to "stable". Up to here all is great.

My question is: How can I merge "log_improve" with the "unstable" branch while completely avoiding all the "stable/unstable" conflicts? I'm only interested in the changes "log_improve" did to the logger class, which is separate from the code "stable" and "unstable" disagree upon.

Comment: Can't you use `git bisect` to find the changes in unstable that introduced the bugs?

Comment: Nope. Unstable does things in a different way than stable (which should be better, after debugging) so it's not simply a matter of one line I accidentally changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, get rid of the conflicts. The merge that creates the conflicts (unstable -> stable) is not committed yet (can't be, as long as you have conflicts); so just reset your working directory, and merge log_improve into first one, then the other of the working branches. Then try the unstable -> stable merge again.

Comment: The problem is I'm far from being ready to merge stable and unstable, as unstable still contains bugs, and I need the logger AND a working stable version with logger to get rid of them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying: merge the logger first into both branches, don't merge the two branches together.

Comment: But since logger was branched from stable, once I try to merge it with unstable it conflicts on all the files in which stable and unstable disagree.

Comment: Ah, there is the problem (that I missed on reading the question)... you should have branched it off the common ancestor. Now I'm not an expert, but in your situation I'd likely format a patch from stable to log, then apply the patch to unstable.